# Cannot understand the logic of regex function in R, for word matching

Tags: r, regex

suppose that i have a long character which includes city names and state names between others.

```
test<-"Ucsd Medical Center, San Diego, California, USA|Yale Cancer Center, New Haven, Connecticut, USA|Massachusetts General Hospital., Boston, Massachusetts, USA|Dana Farber Cancer Institute, Boston, Massachusetts, USA|Washington University, Saint Louis, Missouri, USA|Mount SInai Medical Center, New York, New York, USA|Memorial Sloan Kettering Cancer Center, New York, New York, USA|Carolinas Healthcare System, Charlotte, North Carolina, USA|University Hospitals Case Medical Center; Seidman Cancer Center, Cleveland, Ohio, USA|Vanderbilt University Medical Center, Nashville, Tennessee, USA|Seattle Cancer Care Alliance, Seattle, Washington, USA|National Cancer Center, Gyeonggi-do, Korea, Republic of|Seoul National University Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Severance Hospital, Yonsei University Health System, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Korea University Guro Hospital, Seoul, Korea, Republic of|Asan Medical Center., Seoul, Korea, Republic of|VU MEDISCH CENTRUM; Dept. of Medical Oncology"
```

My goal was to extract all the city names of it. And I achieved it, with some help, by applying:

```
pat="(,.\\w+,)|(,.\\w+.\\w+,)"
gsub("(,\\s)|,","",regmatches(m<-strsplit(test,"\\|")[[1]],regexpr(pat,m)))
```

The problem is now that i want to do the same with the states but i cannot fully understand the logic of the code above. Any help?

Comment: What about [`\s*(?<center>[^,|]+)(?:,\s*(?<city>[^,|]+),(?:\s*(?<state>[^,|]+),(?![^|]*of\|))?\s*(?<country>[^|]+)\|)?`](https://regex101.com/r/kPabCG/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_extract_all` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(test, "(?<=,\\s)[\\w\\s]+(?=,[\\w\\s]+(\\||$))")
```

**Result:**

```
[[1]]
 [1] "California"     "Connecticut"    "Massachusetts"  "Massachusetts"  "Missouri"       "New York"      
 [7] "New York"       "North Carolina" "Ohio"           "Tennessee"      "Washington"     "Korea"         
[13] "Korea"          "Korea"          "Korea"          "Korea"
```

**Notes:**

1. `[\\w\\s]+` matches any word character or space one or more times
2. `(?<=,\\s)` is a positive lookbehind that matches a comma and a space
3. `(?=,[\\w\\s]+(\\||$))` is a positive lookahead that matches a comma, a space or a word character one or more times and a `|` or the end of a string
4. The entire pattern matches any word character or space one or more times only if it *follows* a comma and a space and *followed by* a comma, a space or a word character one or more times and a `|` or the end of a string. Essentially this matches the second last element of each location separated by a comma.

Another method is the nested `str_split` approach, which splits by `|`, and `sapply` `str_split` to each element, splitting by `,` the second time. This method does not require a package, but assumes that state is always the third element for each location:

```
unname(sapply(unlist(str_split(test, "\\|")), 
              function(x) unlist(str_split(x, ", "))[3]))
```

**Result:**

```
 [1] "California"     "Connecticut"    "Massachusetts"  "Massachusetts"  "Missouri"       "New York"      
 [7] "New York"       "North Carolina" "Ohio"           "Tennessee"      "Washington"     "Korea"         
[13] "Korea"          "Seoul"          "Korea"          "Korea"          NA
```

Note that the last element is `NA` because it does not have a third element.

Comment: @firmo23 Glad that this helps. In my original answer, I made a small mistake of writing `\\w\\s` instead of `[\\w\\s]` in the lookahead. My new edit should match all the states now.

Comment: "Kimmel Cancer Center at Johns Hopkins at Sibley Memorial Hospital, Washington, D.C., District of Columbia, USA|Sidney Kimmel Comprehensive Cancer Center at Johns Hopkins, Baltimore, Maryland, USA"   Here it finds only District of Columbia and not Maryland

Comment: @firmo23 see my edit, now it should match it. I added `$` in the lookahead, which also matches the end of a string